# What would be the easiest way to do or simulate color cycling for a face?

Tags: animation, texturing

Is there an easy way to create an [color cycle effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_cycling) like in the image? 
I know that this was usually done manipulating index based colors from a palette. Perhaps a texture can be animated, if so how?

[image]

Image source http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Color_cycling.gif

Comment: Is this in Cycles or BI?

Comment: @gandalf3 I currently render with BI but an answer that also includes cycles would be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to animate the texture mapping.

1. Create an image with the colour gradient you want to use.
2. UV unwrap your object
3. Apply the image in the texture panel
4. Add keyframes for the mapping offset (RMB / insert keyframe).

[image]

For cycles the same thing applies - the keyframes can be added in the Mapping node.

[image]