# add titles using the VSE

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I want to add titles to a video (like the titles in the end of Sintel) using the blender video editor. I made a long Image using GIMP and I want to scroll it in the end of the video. Probably I need to set a dynamic offset, but I didn't find an option for this.

Comment: You could also animate the texutre mapping http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/4887/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-to-do-or-simulate-color-cycling-for-a-face

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved simply:
I went to the first frame, right-clicked on the offset, inserted a keyframe, then I went to the last keyframe, right-clicked on the offset and inserted a keyframe again.

Comment: Note that you can also press I while hovering over a setting to insert a keyframe more quickly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it on the compositor.

Mix the video and the image for the titles. 
For scrolling titles, add a translate node and animate its values.

[image]

**EDIT**

If you must absolutely use the VSE, add a transform srip:

[image]

To animate the values, go to frame where the motion begins, hover the mouse over the Y position for the effect strip and press <kbd>I</kbd> to create a key frame. Go to the end of the effect, change the values and create a new keframe ( using <kbd>I</kbd> again)

Comment: I don't have anything in the node editor

Comment: Sorry, I try to avoid using the VSE as much as I a can... See the updated answer.